# How can I log query parameters using pg_stat_statements?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to identify the heaviest queries in my DB. In the pg_stat_statements, I found a lot of Hibernate-generated queries like:

```
SELECT this_.ID as ID4_1_, this_.version as version4_1_ [...] where cat1_.name in ($1, $2, $3)
```

Why there are parameters like $1, $2... $n instead of actual values? Is it possible to log actual values using pg_stat_statements? $n parameters aren't very useful in this case.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0.2

Comment: Upgrade to the latest point release, your version has a major security hole *and* some serious known bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately it's up to the client, I can only suggest an upgrade.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pg_stat_statements` doesn't log query parameters. That's a large part of the point.

You can use `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf` if you want full parameter logging.

Another option is to use [pg_stat_plans](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans), which collects *query plans* rather than individual statements.

Comment: "Large part of the point": for clarity, pg_stat_statements summarizes query performance based on normalized, non-parameterized versions of the actual queries, so each row in pg_stat_statements potentially represents multiple queries with different parameters. Also pg_stat_plans hasn't been updated since 2013 (https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans/issues/40), so logging or auto_explain may be better approaches.

Comment: Yeah, `pg_stat_plans` was meant to be merged into core to replace/enhance `pg_stat_statements` but got stuck IIRC.